# [[(un)likely]] attributes and do-while loops

Tags: c++, c++20, likely-unlikely

IN SHORT: Is there a place to put the `[[(un)likely]]` attribute so that the control flow at `cond2` is considered likely to take the false branch, *without affecting the possibility of branches at `cond1`*?

```cpp
if (cond1) {
  do {
    foo();
  } while (cond2);
}
```

If I put `[[unlikely]]` in `do [[unlikely]] {` or `do { [[unlikely]]`，does it affect `cond1`？ Since the true-branch of `cond1` is the *ONLY* path that goes into the loop and is the path that *ALWAYS* goes into the loop, according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely):

> Applies to a statement to allow the compiler to optimize for the case where paths of execution including that statement are less likely than any alternative path of execution that does not include such a statement.

it seems that `cond1` is affected.

If I put `[[likely]]` after the loop, e.g. `do { foo(); } while(cond2); [[likely]];`, the attribute is applied to the empty statement. This code is unintuitive and become unclearer whether `cond2` and/or `cond1` are affected.

Btw, the question is infact asking about the semantics of `[[(un)likely]]` attribute, not about implementations neither alternatives such as `__builtin_expect` or breaking the do-while loop to `foo(); while(cond2) [[unlikely]] foo();`.

Comment: What is wrong with `do { foo(); } while(cond2) [[likely]];`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow doesn't compile.

Comment: It seems that the only work around is to define a function similar to `__builtin_expect`, e.g. `inline bool unlikely_cond(bool cond) { if (cond) [[unlikely]] { return true; } else { return false; } }`, then use `unlikely_cond(cond2)`. But I still don't understand the *exact* semantics of `[[(un)likely]]` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but as an alternative one could try this:

```
while (1){
    foo();
    if (cond2) [[unlikely]]
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the correct placement of the attributes:

```
if (cond1) [[likely]] {
    do [[unlikely]] {
        foo();
    } while (cond2);
}
```

The attributes are just examples to show where to place each. The `likely` affects the `if` while the `unlikely` affects the `do/while`. Confusing that the attribute is so far from the condition but that seems to be the place where it compiles.

Comment: But it *forces* the true-branch of cond1 to be likely, which OP wants to avoid. And it still have the question that how the second attribute behaves.

Comment: Elaborated that the attributes are just examples. Better?